# Edit marked as by "Community User"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

I'm pretty sure that this particular one is harmless, but an edit to the answer [How do I get a list of all available fonts for luaotfload?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14162/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-available-fonts-for-luaotfload/14171#14171) got marked as by "Community User".  I'm guessing it was a suggested edit that got approved (perhaps improved?).  But there's no record that I can see of who suggested it nor who approved it, which isn't perfect.

Can moderators see what happened (actually, should I as a 10k user be able to do that from the 10k tools?)?  Whilst ideally it would be obvious to all and sundry who edited what, I'd be okay with knowing that the TeX-SX mods could see who did what.

Comment: Well, I approved it. And it was edited by anonymous one.

Comment: @Leo: Thanks for the clarification.  If it had had an "Approved by ..." then I wouldn't have worried!  The _only_ thing I'm concerned with here is breadcrumbs: being able to easily see what happened in a situation so that I don't have to look any deeper to reassure myself that nothing nasty is going on.

Answer (score 4):

It was an anonymous edit suggestion.  You can verify this by looking at the revision history.  On the right, `suggested` is a link to the details of the suggested edit, including who approved it.

[image: revision listing]

Apparently even people without any account (unregistered or registered) can make edit suggestions. Because there is no user name to be used Community jumps in.

I personally don't like it when people "correct" or "improve" technical details of answers of other people. I think these suggestion should be made as comments instead. The author of the answer can then add them if he or she finds them useful.

Comment: Hmm, the [FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) says that StackExchange is such a site to allow others edit the questions and answers like Wikipedia.

Comment: @Leo: Yes, it is allowed. I just say that IMHO most of the edits suggestions should be made as comments first.

Comment: Although my _instinct_ is to agree with Martin, in practice I feel that the comment-edit cycle would be too long and too often not get done, so I'm happy that these edits can be done.  I just want to be able to _quickly_ see some details of who wrote or approved the edit so that I can be happy that it was an okay edit.

Comment: Also, in this case, I think (though I haven't looked closely) that there was a suggestion along the lines of the edit in the comments already.

Comment: Anonymous (or just joined) users can't put comments. They only have the option to add another answer, or edit an existing one.