# What is "Community" up to, here?

Tags: discussion

This is a follow-up to [Edit marked as by "Community User"](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/edit-marked-as-by-community-user)
I've noticed that some "Community" edits are not associated with any revision. For example, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187371/using-lstinline-in-caption-of-lstlistings-with-multicol)'s a question that is reported to have been modified by "Community":

[image]

However, if I click on it, I don't see any revision history.

[image]

What did "Community" do, in this instance? Is it some automated task that the system runs to bump unanswered questions to the top?

Comment: Community does indeed bump unanswered question up from time to time, where 'unanswered' means no answers with positive scores. There's nothing in the (mod-only) timeline, so I guess this is what has happened. However, I think only a member of staff can be certain.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for that.

Comment: Related: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4639/why-do-old-questions-suddenly-reappear-as-recently-modified

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Occasionally Community [bumps questions that are unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36824/1438) in order to encourage people to answer them. In this case, the one answer to the question has not been upvoted, so Community assumes the [question hasn't *really* been answered](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/).

Comment: Thanks for this, Jon.